# Past simple or past continuous usage

Tags: verbs

John met his wife when he was working in Brussels.

Why is "was working" correct and not worked?

My student noted that after when the past simple is used.

Thank you.

Comment: "Worked" is not wrong in this context, but it would be more natural to say "when he was working" to refer to a period of time during which something happened.

Comment: 'Worked' would not be incorrect, but the punctive-within-a-durative is usually shown by mixing the past simple (met) and past continuous (when/while he was working).